# jQuery: ajaxComplete

Tags: jquery, telerik, radgrid

Is ajaxComplete able to handle any ajax requests invoked in page, for example asp.net ajax or is it only for ajax requests originating using jQuery. I tried to handle Telerik's RadGrid like this without success

```
 $('#RadGrid1').ajaxComplete(function() {

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is only the jQuery ajax methods that will trigger this.  You can manually call it on the "success" event of any other ajax function though.